# How to convert Mac address as String format to Long in scala?

Tags: scala

my question is converting string to long in scala.
where string is format as Mac Address.
for eg:

```
"fe:1a:90:20:00:00"  and "a0:b4:ac:c0:00:01"
```

How to convert in long type using scala.

Comment: Do you want to get one long per address or 6 longs per address (one long per part)? In the first case remove the colons and parse the hex number in the second case split at the colons and then parse.

Comment: Why `Long`, then? You know each value is 8 bit...

Comment: It is possible to get reverse back using python script.

Answer (score 4):

This may help:

```
mac.split(":").map(Integer.parseInt(_,16)).foldLeft(0L) {case (acc,item) => acc*256+item}
```

First operation

```
mac.split(":")
```

gives Array of strings, like Array("fe","1a","90","20","00","00"). Each item of this array is base-16 encoded integer, so we can convert it to array of integers with:

```
val arrayOfInts = mac.split(":").map(Integer.parseInt(_,16))
```

which gives for first example Array(254, 26, 144, 32, 0, 0).

The last thing to do is to convert array of integers to long. Each item of array is in range [0,255], so multiplication on 256 is exactly enough to hold the value, last operation

```
arrayOfInts.foldLeft(0L) {case (acc,item) => acc*256+item}
```

does the conversion. It starts from 0L and for each item multiplies result on 256 and adds item:

```
(((((((0L*256 + 254)*256 + 26)*256) + 144)*256 + 32)*256 + 0)*256) + 0
```

Comment: Thanks Actually I was confused in last step.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in github: 
https://github.com/ppurang/flocke/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/purang/net/flocke/MacAddress.scala

Answer (score 0):

You could use java library

```
def hex2Long(hex: String, removeDelimiter: String = ""): Long = {
    java.lang.Long.valueOf(hex.replaceAll(removeDelimiter, ""), 16)
}


scala> hex2Long("00:00:00:00:2f:59")
res2: Long = 12121
```